# Incorrect selection of kernel headers: expected 4.19.x, got 3.18.x

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, version, buildroot

I'm trying to compile buildroot with a kernel 4.19 but when I'm compiling I have this error :

```
Incorrect selection of kernel headers: expected 4.19.x, got 3.18.x
package/pkg-generic.mk:306: recipe for target '/home/localuser/newOS/buildroot/output/build/linux-headers-STD_LIV_3.18/.stamp_staging_installed' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/localuser/newOS/buildroot/output_agila/build/linux-headers-STD_LIV_3.18.140-vab820/.stamp_staging_installed] Error 1
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

Does anybody now how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You are using some custom kernel headers. You have told Buildroot that your kernel headers are of version 4.19, but that is not true: your kernel headers are from Linux 3.18, so Buildroot complains about that. In the "Toolchain" menu, make sure to indicate the kernel headers version that matches.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to resolve this.

1. Check menuconfig for proper settings in toolchain header
2. In case you want to upgrade to new version then edit files for modification as following
   toolchain/toolchain-common.in
   package/linux-headers/Config.in.host